# Java RandomAccessFile vs. DataInputStream for byte operations

Tags: java, file-io

I need to read bytes from a file.
Is there a difference (e.g. efficiency, memory, runtime, complexity and inelegance of code) between using `RandomAccessFile` and using `DataInputStream`?

The only method I use is readByte().

Similarly for the other direction, is there a difference between `RandomAccessFile` and `DataOutputStream` if all that is needed is writeByte()?
(The fact that `RandomAccessFile` is bidirectional doesn't count, the reading and writing are not connected and cannot share it).

Is there any other object that would better suit that kind of reading and writing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

*If* you are only doing sequential access, by themselves they are essentially equivalent; however a `DataInputStream` around a `BufferedInputStream` around a `FileInputStream` will be considerably more efficient than a `RandomAccessFile`.

Comment: That's very counter-intuitive for me, can you explain why?

Comment: @Xenorose Because of the buffer.

Answer (score 2):

`DataInputStream/DataOutputStream` is totally fine if you only need to read/write it sequentally.

If you need random access (like to an array of bytes) - use `RandomAccessFile`.

I don't think there is any significant difference between them in terms of memory consumption etc. as they are just mediators between JVM and OS.

Comment: To create a DataInputStream to a file, you need to create a FileInputStream, while RandomAccessFile can be created directly (from a path String). Wouldn't that affect efficiency?  I have no need for random access, but I don't know if it really is preferable for use, or what are the drawbacks.

Comment: It won't affect efficiency. When you work with store devices a couple of extra bytes or calls don't matter. It's really negligible. Not even noticeable with a microscope.