# "DataInputStream around a BufferedInputStream around a FileInputStream" or "BufferedInputStream around a DataInputStream around a FileInputStream"?

Tags: java

[Some](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10135472/156458) mentioned using "DataInputStream around a BufferedInputStream around a FileInputStream".

Does "BufferedInputStream around a DataInputStream around a FileInputStream"  also work?
Since the constructors of `BufferedInputStream` and `DataInputStream` take in `InputStream`, it doesn't seem to have any problem.

Do they work in the same way?

Thanks.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? Try achieveing what you want with both techniques, and my bet is you will quickly realize the difference. Especially, try to write a long to the stream for example.

Comment: Thanks. I am trying to understand the usage of the streams. Could you elaborate what they are used for respectively?

Answer (score 2):

> Some mentioned using "DataInputStream around a BufferedInputStream around a FileInputStream".

'Some' was me, and I mentioned it in a context where the API of `DataInputStream` was required.

> Does "BufferedInputStream around a DataInputStream around a FileInputStream" also work?

Yes, but it makes the `DataInputStream` completely pointless. The only reason to add a `DataInputStream` is to use its API, which means it has to be the outermost stream. If it isn't, you may as well just remove it.

It wouldn't work in the question you linked to.